# Fender Rhodes - cable confusion

Tags: piano

I have disassembled and reassembled my Fender Rhodes piano. Sadly there is one cable for which I have forgotton to note where I have to plug it in.
Here is a photo.

[image: Here]

Its not the cable which connects the input jack to the harp. Its coming from the backside of the jack of the harp.

It looks like it is going to be used like a washer. Maybe it is some sort of grounding.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Looks like an earth or ground wire. If the mains plug already has an earth attached to it, there's probably no need to put it anywhere. If the piano works and sounds fine without it, leave it. You may want to touch it onto metal on the piano, listening for hum (or lack of hum). Screwing it onto the frame would maybe mean it doesn't short anything out. - or put it into a plastic sleeve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do need to put it somewhere. It's designed to trap into a screw or nut/bolt on the main frame, so it's properly grounded. The patterning is to prevent vibration from shaking it loose, so if you find any screw without a similar washer, that's probably the one.

The only nut I can see in the image looks like a nylock, or similar 'self-trapping' design which should also stay where it's put, so you're looking for one without that design, a plain screw or nut/bolt that would need that washer type to prevent shaking loose.